# MLlib examples not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying the MLlib examples from this page (on Spark using Scala): [MLlib Page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html#using-mllib-in-scala)

All the examples are throwing the same error error. I have given the one I am getting for Linear Regression:

```
    scala> val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
```

Could someone please guide on what is causing this error? Thank you.

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: I am using Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u4

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? On the latest [HadoopRDD.scala:123](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala#L123) that line is empty

Comment: I am using Spark version 0.9.0. But I think figured out that the issue is related some issue in the bashrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the answer...Apparently, some of the settings in bashrc was conflicting with Spark. Removing the bashrc file fixed the issue.